# Multi conditional attribute selector

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some links for stories, some of which are in pdf, and some of these are special editions. The special editions are prefixed by special-edition in their href.

Here is a simplified html portion of my app

```
<div class='container-node'>
 <a href='1.pdf'>Story 1</a>
 <a href='2.pdf'>Story 2</a>
 <a href='3.pdf'>Story 3</a>
 <a href='special-edition1.pdf'>Special Edition 1</a>
 <a href='4.pdf'>Story 4</a>
 <a href='special-edition2.pdf'>Special Edition 2</a>
</div>
```

What I need is to add a background color for the links ending with the extension pdf, but only if they are not special editions. I am able to apply the following css to handle pdf, but the problem that this also applies to the special edition link. What can I do here?

```
a[href$=".pdf"]{
 background-color: #ADD8E6 ;
}

.container-node{
 background-color: #32CD32;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use a combination of your attribute selector with another not attribute selector as below.

```
a[href$=".pdf"]:not([href*="special-edition"]){
 background-color: #ADD8E6 ;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style> 
    a[href$=".pdf"]:not([href*="special-edition"]){
      background-color: #ADD8E6 ;
    }

    .container-node{
      background-color: #32CD32;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='container-node'>
      <a href='1.pdf'>Story 1</a>
      <a href='2.pdf'>Story 2</a>
      <a href='3.pdf'>Story 3</a>
      <a href='special-edition1.pdf'>Special Edition 1</a>
      <a href='4.pdf'>Story 4</a>
      <a href='special-edition2.pdf'>Special Edition 2</a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```